# MessageBox keeps Displaying even if there are no names that fits inside the array

Tags: c#

I wanted to have a `MessageBox` that pops up if the name isn't in the array, but when I run the program it shows that when I type a name even if it is in the array the `MessageBox` still appears.

```
private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = txtbox1.Text;
    clsStudent [] students = new clsStudent[5];
    students[0] = new clsStudent("Dan","IT","class1",3.9);
    students[1] = new clsStudent("Ben", "IT","class2", 3.8);
    students[2] = new clsStudent("Kardi", "IT","class3",2.4);
    students[3] = new clsStudent("Shaggy", "IT", "class4", 3.2);
    students[4] = new clsStudent("Bernie", " IT", "class5", 2.7);
    for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
    {       
        if(name == students[i].NAME)
        {
            txtbox2.Text = students[i].COURSE;
            txtbox3.Text = students[i].STUDENTCLASS;
            txtbox4.Text = students[i].Gpa.ToString();
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name does not exist");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to `break` out when found, you are not. There are other things, but not relevant to your actual question. Also what happens when there are students with the same name?

Answer (score 1):

See you are iterating the `students` and checking the `name` in each iteration if it doesn't match the message will show. That is why you are getting frequent messages. To avoid this make use of a boolean variable which sets to `true` whenever a matching item found, we can check that variable after completing the iteration. see the code below:

```
bool isExist = false;
for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
{
    if (name == students[i].NAME)
    {
        txtbox2.Text = students[i].COURSE;
        txtbox3.Text = students[i].STUDENTCLASS;
        txtbox4.Text = students[i].Gpa.ToString();
        isExist = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!isExist)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Name does not exist");
}
```

You can get the help of a LINQ as well, like the following:

```
clsStudent selectedStudent = students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NAME == name);
if (selectedStudent != null)
{
    txtbox2.Text = selectedStudent.COURSE;
    txtbox3.Text = selectedStudent.STUDENTCLASS;
    txtbox4.Text = selectedStudent.Gpa.ToString();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Name does not exist");
}
```

Comment: On a list of 5 elements it is not very important, but when you find your name you should break out from the loop

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for the comment, please find the updates

Comment: Now it is better

Comment: @sujithkarivelil what if user types in `ben` what do you think will happen?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: Oh! are you pointing to the case sensitive comparison? That purely depends on how the OP wants to perform the comparison. for the input of `ben` the current code will give the output as `"Name does not exist"` For his implementation he needs to consider case means `.ToLowerCase()` on both sides of comparison operator will fix the issue

Comment: @sujithkarivelil yes, TBH it's not the issue though. If I type in a name no matter the CS factor, I would expect some kind of results to come back as it may be who I am looking for.